# Winnovative - CSS Grid not converted correctly

Tags: css, css-grid, html-pdf, winnovative

I'm using the Winnovative library to convert some HTML to a PDF.
As this works great for a lot of scenarios, it seems to be having issues with CSS grids.

As I cannot share too many specifications, I can however share these images that show the HTML part and the converted result in the PDF.

*HTML element*
[image: HTML element]

*PDF Result*
[image: HTML element]

Small note: both images appear to be different, but they do have the same width in the HTML and PDF. The screenshots I made were from their respective files, keeping the aspect ratio was not possible.

If anyone would have more info about this, I cannot find any specs through Winnovative their website.