# HTML to PDF library Winnovative not converting CSS Grid correctly

Tags: html, css, pdf, html-to-pdf, winnovative

Im using the [Winnovative library](https://www.winnovative-software.com/) to convert HTML Code to PDF Documents. I am having the problem when converting HTML with CSS Grid Code in it: The CSS Grid items are just displayed under each other.

*HTML Code*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.item1 { grid-area: header; }
.item2 { grid-area: menu; }
.item3 { grid-area: main; }
.item4 { grid-area: right; }
.item5 { grid-area: footer; }

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    'header header header header header header'
    'menu main main main right right'
    'menu footer footer footer footer footer';
  gap: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-container > div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Grid Layout</h1>

<p>This grid layout contains six columns and three rows:</p>

<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">Header</div>
  <div class="item2">Menu</div>
  <div class="item3">Main</div>  
  <div class="item4">Right</div>
  <div class="item5">Footer</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

*PDF Output*
[image]

*My input to the topic*

For me it seems as if the Winnovative library cannot work with CSS Grids. As i can see from the [changelogs](https://www.winnovative-software.com/release-notes.aspx) the Library is still getting updates. So maybe it's just a bug in the Library. I will try to contact the support of the library.¨ A very similair [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63615646/winnovative-css-grid-not-converted-correctly) has already been asked but without any answers.

For Plan B:

- I know that tables work with the Winnovative library. Is there a way
  to convert CSS Grids into HTML tables?
- Are there any other ideas and hotfixes for this problem?